# Export Android lib as JAR, and keeping RES folders

Tags: android, eclipse, adt

I have a very short (but yet seems hard") question:
Is there any possible way to export an `Android Library` project in eclipse, and preserving all resources ?

Thank you all

Answer (score 1):

For Android resources, JAR files won't work and full-fledged library projects are the way to go.

See https://developer.android.com/tools/projects/projects-eclipse.html.

[Edit]

Note that you can bundle your plain Java code in a JAR, then reference this JAR in an Android library project that contains resources.
This is useful when you don't want to make the Java code easily readable by anyone, and allows for code obfuscation.

Comment: Interesting, my next question will be what is the best way to obfuscate the source of the JAR file without damaging anything ? thanks !!

Comment: @ElJazouli: ProGuard is used for that: https://developer.android.com/tools/help/proguard.html